# BLAS/LAPACK not installed: How to install it?

Tags: python, c++, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to run `pip install tsne`for python2.7 and I keep on getting the same error. I followed the instructions on http://bickson.blogspot.com/2011/02/installing-blaslapackitpp-on-amaon-ec2.html and installed LAPACK/BLAS which I thought should have solved the problem. Nothing helped. What am I doing wrong? I am less familiar with bash.

```
running build_ext

cythoning tsne/bh_sne.pyx to tsne/bh_sne.cpp

building 'bh_sne' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne_src

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/env/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -Itsne/bh_sne_src/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.o -msse2 -O3 -fPIC -w

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/env/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -Itsne/bh_sne_src/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tsne/bh_sne_src/tsne.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne_src/tsne.o -msse2 -O3 -fPIC -w

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/env/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -Itsne/bh_sne_src/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tsne/bh_sne.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne.o -msse2 -O3 -fPIC -w

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne_src/tsne.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tsne/bh_sne.o -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bh_sne.so -lcblas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/ubuntu/env/work/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/ubuntu/env/work/build/tsne/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3X17dU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/env/work/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/ubuntu/env/work/build/tsne
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/work/bin/pip", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Verify that there _is_ actually a library called `libcblas.a` or `libcblas.so` in `\usr\local\lib`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't have a binary distribution of either cblas or openblas, which are required for tsne according to their [github](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne). However, ATLAS, which is available on Ubuntu, comes with precompiled cblas.

In Ubuntu, debian, that should work with:

```
apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas

If you need to have different compiler options, you'll have to build openblas yourself.

And check that you get libcblas.a in /usr/lib

Edited: Corrected package name.

Comment: it says 'E: unable to locate package atlas'

Comment: hey thanks for your help. Can ou also tell where can I get libcbllas.a from

Comment: See my edit, please try with the updated command. Are you sure you mean "libcbllas.a", not "libcblas.a" ?

Comment: Hey I just checked /usr/lib and I have libblas.so and liblapack.so.

Comment: Following your instruction I can now see libcblas.so.3 but not libcblas.a .I am still not able to run pip install tsne which requires BLAS and it seems that I have it. It is giving the same error as above. What is wrong with my machine?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the atlas you just installed has a different version. You're looking for libcblas.so instead of libcblas.so.3 ; ('so' means dynamically linked, while 'a' is statically linked - so .so should work for tsne).

Please try:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove libatlas3gf-base && sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev`

and then check /usr/lib again.

Comment: Btw. the tsne Readme also has either cblas or openblas listed as requirements: https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne. None of those seem to have binary distributions on Ubuntu, so Atlas could still be a shortcut. If Atlas doesn't give you the right libraries, you'll have to compile either cblas or Openblas your self - please follow the links in the Readme. Be aware that you also need numpy,scipy and cython.

Comment: It's worth building OpenBLAS yourself.  I say this as someone who writes numerical code.

Comment: @MichelMüller Thanks a ton for helping out. This thing worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Download a copy of OpenBLAS and compile it yourself.  Install it into `/usr/local` using `make install`.  There are OpenBLAS and ATLAS packages and whatever else in the official repositories, but their performance is suspect.

Comment: Warning: OpenBLAS doesn't have cblas symbols.